# antl3:Java heap space when testing parser

Tags: antlr3

I'm trying to build a simple config-file reader to read files of this format:

```
A .-
B -...
C -.-.
D -..
E .
```

This is the grammar I have so far:

```
grammar def;

@header {
    package mypackage.parser;
}
@lexer::header { package mypackage.parser; }
file
    :   line+;

line    :   ID WS* CODE NEWLINE;

ID  :   ('A'..'Z')*
    ;

CODE    :   ('-'|'.')*;

COMMENT
    :   '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    |   '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;
```

And this is my test rig (junit4)

```
@Test
public void BasicGrammarCheckGood() {
       String CorrectlyFormedLine="A .-;\n";
       ANTLRStringStream input;
        defLexer lexer;
        defParser parser;

         input = new ANTLRStringStream(CorrectlyFormedLine);
        lexer = new defLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
         parser = new defParser(tokens);
         try {
        parser.line();
         }
         catch(RecognitionException re) { fail(re.getMessage()); } 
   }
```

If I run this test right with a corrected formatted string - the code exits without any exception or output.

However if feed the parser with an invalid string like this : "xA .-;\n", the code spins for a while then exits with a "Java heap space".

(If I start my test with the top-level rule 'file', then I get the same result - with the additional (repeated) output of "line 1:0 mismatched input '' expecting CODE")

What's going wrong here ? I never seem to get the "RecognitionException" for the invalid output ?

EDIT: Here's my grammar file (Fragment), after being provided advice here - this avoids the 'Java heap space' issue.

```
file
    :   line+ EOF;

line    :   ID WS* CODE NEWLINE;

ID  :   ('A'..'Z')('A'..'Z')*
    ;

CODE    :   ('-'|'.')('-'|'.')*;
```

Comment: edit: added the headers - will try the line+ EOF idea...

Comment: same result with the file: line+ EOF; BTW I have 'options' set at all - just simple (package) header directives - the full .g file is now on my original post (I modified the package names only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your lexer rules match zero characters (an empty string):

```
ID  :   ('A'..'Z')*
    ;

CODE    :   ('-'|'.')*;
```

There are, of course, an infinite amount of empty strings in your input, causing your lexer to keep producing tokens, resulting in a heap space error after a while.

Always let lexer rules match at least 1 character.

### EDIT

Two (small) remarks:

1. since you put the `WS` token on the hidden channel, you don't need to add them in your parser rules. So `line` becomes `line : ID CODE NEWLINE;`
2. something like `('A'..'Z')('A'..'Z')*` can be written like this: `('A'..'Z')+`

Comment: Thanks for this - changing the match to a pattern like '('A'..'Z')('A'..'Z')*' - this has indeed stopped the loop/heap-dump error. Now I'm confused why the test doesn't throw an exception when I provide an invalid input "xA .-\n"; - but I do get some output "line 1:0 no viable alternative at character 'x'"...

Comment: The parser recovers from the invalid input (after printing some warnings to your `stderr`). More info [here](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Error+reporting+and+recovery) and [here](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Custom+Syntax+Error+Recovery).

Comment: Great thanks for the help on this. I'll edit my main question and then check as accepted answer.

Comment: Great - thanks for the additional info regarding WS-handling as well - very useful. And the shortened syntax:  (xx)* -> (x)+ .